# Is this the same true for the Frobenius form?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $E$ is an outer product $E=uv^*$, then $\|E\|_2=\|u\|_2\|v\|_2$. Then is the same true for the Frobenius norm? Prove it or give a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any column-vectors $u,v$, we have
$$
\|uv^*\|_F = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}((uv^*)(uv^*)^*)} = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(uv^*vu^*)} = \sqrt{v^*vu^*u} = \sqrt{v^*v}\sqrt{u^*u} = \|v\|_2 \cdot \|u\|_2
$$

Comment: why$ \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(uv^*vu^*)} = \sqrt{v^*vu^*u} $?

Comment: @Kristy for any matrices $A,B$, $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$.  For any $1 \times 1$ matrix, $\operatorname{tr}(k) = k$.

Comment: I do not think this works. It should be v in F norm instead of 2 norm

Comment: @yiG $v$ is a column-vector, not a matrix. There is no distinction between $\|u\|_2$ and $\|u\|_F$.